# How to join two table and using the second table to override the first one?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

I'm working on a to-do app with multiple projects sharing a preconfigured checklist and what I want is the ability to modify upon the included checklist per project.

What I have in mind is having 2 separate tables: 1 for the shared one and 1 for the modifications per project like so

```
CREATE TABLE checklist (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    title text NOT NULL,
    description text NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE modification (
    project_uuid uuid,
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    title text NOT NULL,
    description text NOT NULL,
);
```

Each project will have it's own checklist based on the preconfigured one that users can modify and any modification made to the shared one will be reflected to all the projects.

Is there a way to use the second "modification" table to modify on top of the "checklist" table? If a certain row isn't found in "modification" it would grab it from "checklist" and if a row exists in both table, the one in "modification" would override the one in "checklist"?

For example if I had:

```
SELECT * FROM checklist;
id | title  | description
---+--------+-------------
 1 | Item 1 | Dummy item
 2 | Item 2 | Dummy item

SELECT * FROM modification;
project_uuid | id | title  | description          |
-------------+----+--------+----------------------+
  1          | 2  | Item 2 | Modified description |
```

I'd want this as the result

```
 id |  title | description          |
----+--------+----------------------+
  1 | Item 1 | Dummy item           |
  2 | Item 2 | Modified description |
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use left join and [coalesce()](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/functions-conditional#functions-coalesce-nvl-ifnull) function:

```
select  c.id, 
        coalesce(m.title, c.title)             as title, 
        coalesce(m.description, c.description) as description
  from checklist c 
       left join modification m on c.id=m.id
```